# Examining SQLAlchemy query results in Pyramid

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm trying to add a method to an (quite big) existing project  writtent in python with **pyramid framework** and **sqlalchemy ORM**. I've wanted to execute an sql query with sqlalchemy but I've never developped with pyramid or sqlalchemy before. So I would like to test it and **see if the query returns what I'm expecting** but I don't want to add useless code to test my query ( like a new template, a view etc). My SQL query is :

```
select a.account_type, u.user_id from accounts a inner join account_users au on a.account_id=au.account_id inner join users u on u.user_id=au.user_id where u.user_id = ?;
```

And my method is :

```
def find_account_type_from_user_id(self,user_id):
    '''
    Method that finds the account type (one/several points of sale...)
    from the id of the user who is linked to this account

    :param user_id:
    :return:(string) account_type
    '''

    q = self.query(Account)\
        .join(AccountUser)\
        .join(User)\
        .filter(User.user_id == user_id)\
        .one()

    return q
```

ps: I've already searched on the internet but I only find things like : unit tests etc and I've never did that. (Noob's sorry).

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are a must to test new services, fixes, refactoring code, etc, you need a good collection of unit tests.
You can start [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/tests.html).

Comment: Ok I'll see that. But I've build apps with Symfony and there you can install a special Bundle for the docs and there you have a page like : mysebsite.com/doc where you have all your methods and you can test them ( you can enter some input values and you receive the response of your method).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to see SQLAlchemy query content

- Set `sqlalchemy` logging level to INFO - see instructions https://opensourcehacker.com/2016/05/22/python-standard-logging-pattern/
- Use [pyramid_debugtoolbar](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_debugtoolbar/en/latest/) and it shows all queries your view made
- Execute query interactively using [pshell](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/pscripts/pshell.html) - no views need to be added

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try your suggestions :)